# Html.Raw and more Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, razor, replace

I have this code in Razor (.cshtml file):

```
<div class="category">
    @Html.Raw(Model.CategoryLinks(" | ").Replace("Fotogallery", ""))
</div>
```

I want to replace not only "Fotogallery" with NULL, but also other 3 values:

- "videogallery" "musicgallery"

How can I do it? Can you help me please?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You can't replace any part of a string with NULL. You want to replace it with empty string (`""`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.Replace()` returns the string with the replacement, so you can chain calls, e.g.:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.CategoryLinks(" | ").Replace("Fotogallery", "").Replace("videogallery", "").Replace("musicgallery", ""))
```

Comment: Thanksssss

but how can leave this symbol " | " 

for example  "FOTOGALLERY | MUSIC | SPORT"

i want replace FOTOGALLERY and | with ""

and see only "MUSIC | SPORT"

Thanksss

Comment: i want replace non only "Fotogalley" but also " | ", but if i do Replace("Fotogallery | ","") don't work!